# EC2 Persistent Spot Request keeps reviving

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Earlier today I created a AWS EC2 Spot Request and inadvertently made it a persistent Spot Request. Since then I didn't need the machine and have been trying various ways of cancelling my Spot Request. Here is the behavior I see

1. Cancel Spot Request in console, see the state to the effect of "instance terminated by user and instance running"
2. Terminate the EC2 instance created by the Spot Request
3. Wait 0-5 minutes
4. EC2 Spot Request UI shows a new Spot Request which is identical to the old one except the Request ID is different

I would expect as per the docs, nothing else happens after this.

I also tried terminating the instance first, then canceling the Spot Request. The docs however explicitly say cancel the request, then terminate the instance. Beyond that, I also cancelled a request before fulfillment but the Spot Request came back.

Am I doing something wrong or is this legitimately a bug?

I already filed a ticket with AWS, but don't know when I will hear back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking through the UI made me remember I agreed to try out the new Spot Request console. As it turns out, that was the source of the problem:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=683718&#683718

Comment: I saw an issue tonight where I suspect the Amazon Elastic MapReduce Spark/Hadoop Cluster Wizard created a spot fleet request that could only be effectively cancelled in the new Spot Request console.  I played whackamole with the spot requests and instances tonight for a while before trying the new console and noticing the fleet request, which was not shown in the old console, although spot requests were popping up over and over in the old console.

Answer (score 1):

How to find the new console: click on the quote bubble.

[image]

The url for the new console appears to be https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2sp/v1/spot/dashboard?region=us-east-1#